# How to make shorthand for countModules?

Tags: php, templates, template-framework

I'm tired of typing `$this->countModules('...')`. Is there a way to make alias to that function, something similar as in JavaScript when I just do `var alias = myFunction`?

I have tried assigning `$this` to a global variable, and than use wrapper function and I have tried `use $this->countModules as m` but none of that works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is simply no need to do this. As @Bakual has already said, your approach is bad practice.

For starters, you are wrapping a function within a function unnecessarily when it's not required. You are then returning `JFactory::getDocument()->countModules(...)`, meaning you are calling the `JFactory` class, then calling `JDocument` which has to check if it already exists before creating it, and then the `countModules()` function. Overall you are slowing down the process.

Keep things simple by sticking to `$this->countModules()`

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out, after some more tinkering:

```
//Shorthand for countModules function
function m($arguments) {
    return JFactory::getDocument()->countModules($arguments);
}
```

Comment: You can do that, but it's certainly not good practice.

Comment: @Bakual why is that so?